# How do I use reflection to access a private method?

Tags: java, nosuchelementexception

I'm trying to access private method within reverse() in Java.

I've tried my best to make it possible, but failed at last. Can anyone help me to solve this? I just need a success run. Maybe I can change the code. Maybe I'm doing this the wrong way?

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Dummy.foo()
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2130)
    at Test.main(Dummy.java:22)

Process completed.
```

My code:

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class Dummy{
    private void foo(String name) throws Exception{
        BufferedReader n = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Please give name: ");
    name = n.readLine();
    StringBuffer o = new StringBuffer(name);
    o.reverse();
    
    System.out.print("Reversed string: "+o);
    }
}

class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Dummy d = new Dummy();
        Method m = Dummy.class.getDeclaredMethod("foo");
        //m.invoke(d);// throws java.lang.IllegalAccessException
        m.setAccessible(true);// Abracadabra 
        m.invoke(d);// now its OK
    }
}
```

Comment: The best fix is probably to remove the unused parameter `String name`

Comment: The best fix is to not use a private method here, and call the method directly instead of resorting to reflection.

Comment: It seems, you don't have too much experience in Java coding. At that level, I'd recommend to not use esoteric tricks like overriding access control using reflection. There's almost always a better solution. So, maybe you want to describe your original requirement in more detail.

Comment: I'm sorry, forget to mention that it was my case study question request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`getDeclaredMethod`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-) needs you to pass the parameter types so that it can resolve overloaded methods.

Since your `foo` method has a single parameter of type `String`, the following should work:

```
Method m = Dummy.class.getDeclaredMethod("foo", String.class);
```

And of course you also need to change the `invoke` call to pass a string.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use [MethodHandles](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.html). Your `Test` class, rewritten to use `MethodHandles`. (Class `Dummy` is unchanged.)

```java
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodType;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
        MethodType methodType = MethodType.methodType(void.class, String.class);
        try {
            lookup = MethodHandles.privateLookupIn(Dummy.class, lookup);
            MethodHandle handle = lookup.findVirtual(Dummy.class, "foo", methodType);
            handle.invoke(new Dummy(), "");
        }
        catch (Throwable x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Inspired by [Method Handles in Java | Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-method-handles)